# Arquillian + Glassfish embedded

Tags: ejb, bean-validation, jboss-arquillian, glassfish-embedded

I'm trying to write integration tests to my jee application with arquillian and embedded ejb server (glassfish 3.1.2.2). My application uses jsr 303 bean validation. When I try to execute test I receive:

```
Caused by: org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishException: PlainTextActionReporterFAILUREorg.jvnet.hk2.config.TransactionFailure: HV000100: Unable to parse META-INF/validation.xml.Could not change the attributes: HV000100: Unable to parse META-INF/validation.xml.
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ConfiguratorImpl.configure(ConfiguratorImpl.java:71)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishImpl.configure(GlassFishImpl.java:71)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishImpl.(GlassFishImpl.java:65)
```

I found same problem on https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-17381. Is there anybody who faced and resolved this issue?

Thanks

Comment: What is the reason to use embedded glassfish specifically? What is your target container you are deploying your app to?

Comment: I've just managed with this issue by use of remote glassfish instance. Thanks

Comment: Embedded containers are currently struggling due to lack of classpath isolation, hence you get all what's in there.

Comment: Did you ever try the workarounds listed in the GF JIRA?

Comment: Yes but I did not succeed.